# Web page acts like page refresher or slideshow

Tags: asp.net

I have a series of pages that displays certain statistic.  I want to create asp.net page that navigate to each of those pages on single page in certain time interval.  (Like slide show) 
How should I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about JavaScript and an IFRAME? You can change the target of the IFRAME with JavaScript code (in an ASP.NET page) at an interval

**UPDATE -- CODE SAMPLE**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var s = {
            windowIndex: 0,
            links : ["http://www.bing.com","http://msdn.com","http://url.com"],
            switchFrameSrc : function () {
                var newurl = s.links[s.windowIndex];        
                $(".uriLabel").text(newurl);
                $(".frame").attr("src",newurl);
                s.windowIndex++;    
                if (s.windowIndex >= s.links.length) {
                    s.windowIndex = 0; // reset loop    
                }
            }
        };
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            s.switchFrameSrc();
            window.setInterval(function () { s.switchFrameSrc(); }, 5000);
            // set interval, interval in milliseconds 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="uri"><span class="uriLabel">URL goes here</span></div>

    <IFRAME class="frame" src="http://www.url.com" width="800" height="600"></IFRAME>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks.  On what method of Iframe should I call the each page and where should I add the timer?  Would it be possible to give a psuedo-code?  I would imagine I should use SetTimeOut and assign each page to the url property of Document object.  But, not clear how I should do this.

Comment: That will be very helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, the only way that you can achieve this is to have an "iframe" for each page that you want to display and toggle the visibility using jQuery or Javascript.

Hope this Helps!!